# How do I sync an user's preferences with their subscribed topics on FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an application where an user authenticated through Firebase specifies a list of topics and the system saves it to Cloud Firestore. 
The database might have a structure similar to **users/{userId}/interests** and inside that collection I would have a list of documents with values like "news", "cooking", etc.
Another set of users could then decide to send a notification directed only to people interested in a specific topic. 
It seems the best way to do so is through FCM's topic function. 
So my question is: how do I make sure that my Firebase User's preferences in the database are synchronized to their device's topic subscriptions? Should I query the database during the app's splash screen and subscribe to each topic on every app open?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to re-subscribe to an FCM topic every time that the app opens.  Once you subscribe to a topic, it will stay subscribed until you explicitly un-subscribe or until the Android app's instance ID changes or is invalidated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you referring to GCM's App Instance ID or FCM's Instance ID? 
I read that the latter changes when the app's data is deleted and that's fine. Does the ID not change periodically too?

Comment: Those are really the same thing - FCM is the successor/replacement for GCM, both APIs refer to the same instance ID.  To see when then instance ID changes, refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.